# Date added/created column for a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

Is it possible to insert the date/time when a row is inserted into a google spreadsheet.

Please note this is different from the NOW() method, which will insert the current date time as your view the spreadsheet...

The main purpose of this is to turn the google spreadsheet into a 'google form' which can be sent out to collect feedback and will have a history of when responses were given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like the below in a [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)?  This should set the value of the a set column at the time the edit is made.

If you are unfamiliar with GAS, select "Tools"->"Script Editor" from Spreadsheet menu.  Select "Blank Project", then wipe out what's there and replace with this.  Save it (name is unimportant) and go back to your Spreadsheet to try an edit and see results.

```
function onEdit() {
    var dateColNum = 6 //column F
    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    //set date in same row as edit happens, at fixed column  
    ss1.getActiveSheet().getRange(ss1.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), dateColNum, 1, 1).setValue(new Date())
}
```

Comment: Sigh, I wish there was an equivalent for free users. I guess I'm just too hardcore for their target market